# Can you add r code to a beamer note in R Markdown?

Tags: beamer, rmarkdown

For example,

````
\note{
```{r, ex1}
curve(x)
```
}
````

When I try, my tex file contains the following

```
\note{
![](.../figure-beamer/ex1-1.pdf)<!-- -->
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik you can't use r chunks inside latex environments or macros. As a workaround, you can use the rmarkdown syntax for notes (but make sure to not include any fragile content into notes)

````
---
title: ""
output: 
  beamer_presentation: 
    toc: false
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
---


test

::: notes
```{r,echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
:::
````

[image]